# Content or .rd files generated with R

Tags: r

I thought that rd files were just documentation files but I have a list of .rd files which contain several variables inside. 
Do you know how one could generate such files?
The files is several Mb.
Here's how I open it.

```
samp_fn <- file.path("data/file.rd")
samp_env <- new.env()
load(envir=samp_env,samp_fn)
samp_env
<environment: 0x559d0f4c8750>
```

Here's the content of the file

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the examples? Can you post the content of such a file (using code formatting)

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: "rd" is just a file extension that happens to be used by R documentation files. People can hijack it for other things. In this case, it looks like someone has saved their R objects into a file and given it the rd extension instead of the usual Rdata or rda.

Comment: I think the explanation of Hong Ooi is right: It's probably a misspelling of `rda`.

Comment: Good to know, thanks guys!